# How to determine which Apps are launched most by the user?

Tags: android

I am trying to build a sort of launcher.

I would like to have the possibility to present to the user the apps he uses most.

Is there any way to determine which Apps are launched more often by the user?

I am not aware of any system "counter" that does that, and I have found nothing in the documentation and in SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get this information from the OS, because of privacy concerns. You can start collecting this information when people install your launcher and start using to launch apps, because you'll know which apps they start, but you have to start with some common list of apps initially, which likely will be useless to your users. You can also import their current home screen from the Launcher (and TouchWiz, and HTC Sense), but that does not scale easily for all possible launchers people might be currently using (Nova, GO Launcher, Facebook Home, and so on).

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating an Android launcher, then you are responsible for displaying the android Applications installed and while clicking on the application icon that you listed, you are the one who is opening up the clicked app. So you can keep the count whenever you open a particular app and do accordingly.

Whenever you open an application, just save an open counter against the application package name of the app that you opened.

Comment: thanks Eldhose M Babu, but what I am actually try to find out is in general which apps are used most, even if they are not launched by my application

Comment: unfortunately, that is not possible Lisa... :(. You can make use of getRunning tasks to get the running tasks at that time. I think you can get an initial data by checking the currently running tasks.